# The only mitsva is to get better for person in severe psychiatric episode

Tags: health-safety-shmira, psych-mentalhealth, shoteh-mental-incompetent

Let's say that  someone ch''v suffers from a severe psychiatric disorder, which can alter judgment and reality testing,  e. g. Schizoaffective disorder (elements of schizophrenia and bi-polar disorder) and has been told by his rav,  as this is the case frequently that   his only mitzva is 'to get better'.  What is the sense of this expression 'to get better'?

Comment: Agree with Jay's comments. What would qualify him as better is a doctor who would evaluate that. I'm not following...

Comment: have edited question. re; first and now only question it is generally regarded by psychiatrists that with such illness one may have no epsodes for years but still retain the diagnosis, therefore one may be functioning in society but still defined by diagnosis and perhaps would relapse if they stopped medication

Comment: `and has been told his only mitzva is 'to get better', what would qualify him as 'better'.` It seems like only whoever used the term "better" can know what he meant by it.

Comment: Could you please [edit] in more information about the "has been told his only mitzva is 'to get better'"? Who told him this? Was it meant literally, as a matter of Jewish law, figuratively, or merely as a way of providing emotional support? Do you know what the basis of the statement was? As @mevaqesh said, it's very hard for us to define a term in the context of a statement we don't know the real meaning of. If you know someone in this situation, he or she should determine the best things to focus on by consulting his/her rabbi and relevant healthcare professionals.

Comment: @yonatanhakatan please check my edit if it is close to your intent.

Comment: Can you please give some suggestions as to what 'to get better' could mean? eg: (a) be told by the therapist that the patient should return for a check in 6 months or (b) be told that the patient need not return or (c) be told that the patient is much improved but still has a way to go.

Comment: yes kouty that is a good edit. what do i do to accept it.?

Comment: @IsaacMoses Needs to be reopened and protected because this person could be more in need of answers than we know. Never mind that it's not our job. Life first!

Comment: @SAH Are you suggesting that this community, using this Q&A format, is any more equipped to offer qualified, effective healthcare advice than it is halachic advice? If anything, it's less so, and the danger associated with hubris is greater.

Comment: @IsaacMoses If by chance the community can offer anything of use to this poster (or, note, the hypothetical person in question), it is well worth it. I sorely doubt that shutting his question down for lack of clarity will cause a person with schizoaffective disorder to seek help in the right places. Excuse the tone of this comment. I don't intend bitterness. I think the stakes are very high.

Comment: @SAH Let's continue this discussion of site policy [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4250/should-qa-rules-be-lifted-when-a-question-implies-that-the-asker-is-facing-high).

Comment: I misunderstood the point of this site and agree with Isaac Moses, although I appreciate SAH's generous comments and concern. @Kouty thank you for thoughtful reply also. It is a very complex issue and I understand why it is not for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very important question.

First ShizoAffective disorder is not a continuous and irreversible  problem of Shote (see DSM 5), almost all mental illnesses has full remission states, or partial remission. Maybe that in certain acute situation, little quantities of time, he is Shote. Second. The answer, your only mitsva is to get better needs to be translated. The first of all step is to treat yourself in way to get a maximum of independence and mastery, a minimum of invalidating symptoms. After this step you can and you need to make all mitsvot. The man and the illness have to be considered as two entities. The condition for mitsvot is free will. one man who is in a very acute psychotic & / manic / depressive state loses his free will (see gemara Ketubbot 20a). Pharmacological, psychotherapeutic and rehabilitating treatments help to regain free will. So, in a state in which the amount of free will is low (See for instance Kiddushin 40a an exemple of loss of free will concerning particular things, according to some Rishonim), often, the only free will is to make all to get better, to make a great effort to get the better treatment.

Comment: `ShizoAffective disorder is not a permanent problem of Shote` source?